# What is a good introductory book on mathematical risk theory?

Tags: reference-request, risk-assessment

I'm looking for a book that introduces the following concepts and illustrates them with examples and exercises:

- [Risk measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_measure)s (Value at Risk, Expected Shortfall, distortion risk measures, and more)
- (Modern) Portfolio theory
- Different notions of [risk aversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion) (Arrow-Pratt and others)
- Utility functions (Von Neumann-Morgenstern)
- Stochastic orderings and stochastic dominance

And perhaps other important, related topics of which I am not aware. Do you know a good example of such a book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Stochastic Finance. An Introduction in discrete time](https://www.degruyter.com/viewbooktoc/product/468290?rskey=0Evd3b&result=4). by Foellmer and Schied gives an excellent introduction in chapters 2-4.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to [Mathematical Methods in Risk Theory](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=70gBCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=risk+theory+maths&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOhrbRysXYAhUBsI8KHSwWAFoQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Buhlmann. It has a very good selection and has some recent works in the mathematics of risk theory.

See also: [Modern Actuarial Risk Theory](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=6O7HY1A0qAEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=risk+theory+book+discussing+risk+aversion+utility+functions+portfolio+theory+stochastic+ordering&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXz8iny8XYAhWBN48KHSIpCD44ChDoAQgxMAM#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Kaas et.al. and [Introduction to Mathematical Portfolio Theory](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=_7xKKdifMfkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=risk+theory+book+discussing+risk+aversion+utility+functions+portfolio+theory+stochastic+ordering&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpiumSy8XYAhUFSo8KHSKPDEwQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Joshi and Paterson.